# Как получить список столбцов из запроса не обращаясь к таблице. PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Возникла проблема, в котором мне нужно получить список столбцов из запроса, НО запрос с данными - это не таблицы, где через `information_schema` можно получить данные, а конкретно запрос по типу:

```
SELECT id, name, type..;
```

И вот эти имена мне нужно получить id, name, type. Как видите я не указываю название таблицы, поскольку в запросе этого не будет известно.

Подскажите, как можно получить набор имен столбцов из такого запроса?

Comment: Из вопроса не очень понятно какую именно проблему вы решаете и не очень понятно где именно вы хотите получить этот список столбцов и в какой именно форме.

Comment: В данном случае вы должны использовать сервисные возможности провайдера данных который вы используете. У всех заслуживающих внимания провайдеров данных есть функционал позволяющий получить информацию о структуре возвращенных кортежей данных. Если существует потребность подготовить контейнер например при костюмном экспорте в excel в python я использую psycopg2 делаю запрос с LIMIT 1, анализирую полученный кортеж, затем уже выгружаю в готовую книгу.